# Proximity detection with Bluetooth LE and iOS

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been investigating Bluetooth LE a bit, especially after reading some rumors apple may be implementing some sort of "iWallet" for payments using this technology. For those more fmailar with the technology, could I use it to painlessly connect to devices together by moving them really close and hitting a button without the hassle of pairing? I.E, if i want to send a file to my friend who's next to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this small code to quickly get started with iBeacons - hope it helps 
https://github.com/manishnath/iBeaconCenter
Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 3):

BTLE on iOS does not require a full pairing step unless you want a secure connection. However, it does not have the bandwidth for file transfers. It is meant for tiny amount of data. Think heart monitors and temperature sensors.  BTLE does not replace full Bluetooth or WiFi. It augments it.

Answer (score 1):

You can already use the inbuilt bluetooth using the `GameKit` framework, however be aware that this will only work for iOS-to-iOS. You can't use gamekit for multiplatform communications.

Another option would be `Bonjour`, or otherwise you would have to create a webserver backend. I.e. Send the file to a web service which then sends back to your friends phone.

This page shows some example code on how to detect peers that are close to you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/FindingPeerswithPeerPicker/FindingPeerswithPeerPicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH102-SW1

Here is a good general starting point: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/networking.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a super simple bluetooth LE proximity-based sharing project for iOS- you could check out the source and see if my setup would work for you, or drag the project into your app and just use the delegate methods to share an array of strings between nearby phones.

For example, you could share an array of user IDs or photo IDs between phones over Bluetooth LE that the receiver could use to download larger amounts of data (a user profile, a large photo) from a web service.

[SimpleShare - Easy Proximity-based Sharing for iOS](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)